# Absolute convergence, conditional convergence or divergence of a series based on a variable

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

So I have this question here:

> Determine the values of the constant $q$ so that the series $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln^q(n)}}$$ is absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent.

I assume I can just approach this directly.

For absolute convergence, we have:

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln^q(n)}}\right|$$

Could I just use the integral test on this?

This would mean that we have $\displaystyle \int_{3}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\ln^q(x)}}\right|dx$. Since the integral is going to infinity, we really have:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{3}^{t}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\ln^q(x)}}dx$$.

So if $u=\ln(x)$, this gives $du=\frac1{x}dx{}$ so we get $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^q}}du$ or $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{u^{q/2}}du$.

So this means that $\frac{q}{2}>1$ or $q>2$.

For conditional convergnce, we have by the alternating series test, we have that for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln^q(n)}}$, $b_n = \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln^q(n)}}$.

This means that as long as $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln^q(n)}} $ = $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln^{q/2}(n))} $ does not diverge, we are good. So from what I can see this will only happen if $\frac{q}{2}>0$. So this means that $q>0$.

Finally, this directly shows that the series will diverge if $q<0$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: It is convergent for $q=-2$.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about absolute convergence, if $q=-2$ we get $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{u^{-1}} du$ or $\displaystyle \int u du$ which would diverge at infinity right?

Comment: It is conitionally converent for $q=-2$ by Alternating Series Test.

Comment: Oh yeah. I see it. Then we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ which will go to $0$ by L'hopital's rule.

Is the rest of my work correct?

Comment: What about other negative values of $q$?

Comment: Oh yeah good point. So I guess it'll technically converge for all values of $q$ except $q=0$. Is that the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=-p^{-1},$ where $p> 0.$ The function ${x\over \ln x}$ is increasing for $x>e.$ Thus the function ${x^p\over \ln(x^{p})}={1\over p}{x^p\over \ln x}$ is increasing for $x>e^{1/p}. $ So is the function ${x\over (\ln x)^{1/p}}=x(\ln x)^{r}.$ Therefore for $r=q/2<0$ the series is convergent by the Leibniz theorem.